# How to really use RTE (Rich Text Editors) in your application?

Tags: ckeditor, tinymce, richtextbox, draftjs, rte

**Intro:**

I am working at a project which contains a lot of forms and I'd like to integrate **rich text editors** for some fields.

Regarding the flow, it seems that behind the scenes your text from the editor is a in a **specific format** (e.g. HTML).

**Problem:**

As I want to save that information in a database, what is the best way to do it? For each RTE property to have 2 values stored: plaintext + formatted?

Another concern is how should I validate my formatted field?

I use mongoose for data storage and basically I want to apply my current schema on the plaintext, but in the future I want to serve the formatted field to client.

**Your opinion**

I found some online tools or libraries that offer also a community edition: react-rte, TinyMCE, Draft.js, CKEditor. Any recommendations or any suggestions regarding how to choose between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve TinyMCE content as both HTML and plaintext.

Let’s say you have initialized the editor on a textarea with id=”myTextarea”. First access the editor using that same id, then call getContent().

```
var myContent = tinymce.get("#myTextarea").getContent();
```

Or, instead of accessing the editor by id, you can access the *active editor*.

```
var myContent = tinymce.activeEditor.getContent();
```

These will both return the editor content marked up as HTML.

To retrieve the content as plaintext, use `getContent({format: 'text'})`.

Resources:

- TinyMCE Documentation: [getContent](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.editor/#getcontent)
- TinyMCE Article: [How to get content in TinyMCE](http://How%20to%20get%20content%20and%20set%20content%20in%20TinyMCE)